# What is Unity's equivalent of Windsor's Release

Tags: unity-container, release

I have some unmanaged resources in classes I'm injecting into controllers that I need to dispose once the controller is disposed (otherwise I'll have memory leak). I have looked at IUnityContainer and did not find a Release (or similar) method that allow me to do that.

After some trial and error (and reading), it seems to me that Unity do not keep track of what is going on about the types it creates. This is way different from Windsor, where I can call Release and the entire object graph will be release. This is actually one of the points of having a container in the first place (object lifecycle management). I should not need to call Dispose directly the container should be able to do that for me in the proper order/objects.

So, my question is, how can I tell Unity that an object is no longer needed and should be disposed?

If there is no way of doing that, is there a way to change the lifecycle to per web request?

As a note, changing the container is not an option. Unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

You will have to look at the different lifetime managers in Unity. The ContainerControlledLifetimeManager will call dispose on every item it creates. Unfortunately this manager acts as a singleton for resolved objects so might not be appropriate for you.

The other alternative is to create your own lifetime manager which keeps track of objects that it creates and when the container is disposed just disposes every object.